# can use single input name to multiple input name?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I created single input previous code . i have used name for  this code "upfrontmippc" .  now i have four input fields same functionality ? here my code updated . this code Working when  i use single input fields. now i changed four input fields .assign this function four input fields  Not working

```
<input name="upfrontmippc" id="upfrontmippc" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" 
      onChange="javascript:upfrontMIPPcChanged(true)" />
```

I have assign Four fields in my New Design:  this value assign four time in my new code ?

```
<div class="col-md-2  padding-Zero">
<input  name="upfrontmippc"  class="txt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:upfrontMIPPcChanged(true)" />
 </div>
```

MY script:

```
 /*state holders*/
/*WARNING!! this script must be above all other js scripts*/
var userChangedUpfrontMIPPc_=false;
var userChangedUpfrontMIPAmt_=false;
var userChangedMonthlyMIP_=false;
var userChangedDownPaymentPc_=false;
var userChangedDownPaymentAmt_=false;

userChangedUpfrontMIP=false;
userChangedMonthlyMIP=false;
userChangedSSMonthlyMIP=false;

function userChangedUpfrontMIPPc(state)//state=true or false
    {
         userChangedUpfrontMIPPc_=state;
    }
function userChangedUpfrontMIPAmt(state)//state=true or false
    {
         userChangedUpfrontAmt_=state;
    }
function userChangedMonthlyMIP(state)//state=true or false
    {
         userChangedUpfrontMIP_=state;
    }
function userChangedDownPaymentPc(state)//state=true or false
    {
         userChangedDownPaymentPc_=state;
    }
function userChangedDownPaymentAmt(state)//state=true or false
    {
         userChangedDownPaymentAmt_=state;
    }


function getMIP(str)
{
     //get user input
     ficorange=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['ficorange'].value;
     //loantype=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['loantype'].value;
     purchaseprice=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['purchaseprice'].value;
     downpaymentpc=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['downpaymentpc'].value;
     downpaymentamt=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['downpaymentamt'].value;

    for (i=0;i<4;i++ )
    {
      if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['loantype'][i].checked==true)
        {
          loantype=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.loantype[i].value;
        }
    }

    //seconds and silent seconds
   totalseconds_=0.0;
   totalsilentseconds_=0.0;
   secondV=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['second'].value;
   if (secondV=="")  { secondV="0";  } 
   secondV_=parseFloat(secondV);
   secondT=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['secondtype'].value;
   if (secondT=="normal")  {totalseconds_+= secondV_;} else {totalsilentseconds_+= secondV_;}

  thirdV=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['third'].value;
   if (thirdV=="")  { thirdV="0";  } 
   thirdV_=parseFloat(thirdV);
   thirdT=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['thirdtype'].value;
   if (thirdT=="normal")  {totalseconds_+= thirdV_;} else {totalsilentseconds_+= thirdV_;}

   fourthV=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['fourth'].value;
   fourthT=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['fourthtype'].value;
   if (fourthV=="")  { fourthV="0";  }
   fourthV_=parseFloat(fourthV);
   if (fourthT=="normal")  {totalseconds_+= fourthV_;} else {totalsilentseconds_+= fourthV_;}


   fifthV=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['fifth'].value;
   fifthT=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['fifthtype'].value;
   if (fifthV=="")  { fifthV="0";  }
   fifthV_=parseFloat(fifthV);
   if (fifthT=="normal")  {totalseconds_+= fifthV_;} else {totalsilentseconds_+= fifthV_;}


   sixthV=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['sixth'].value;
   sixthT=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['sixthtype'].value;
   if (sixthV=="")  { sixthV="0";  }
   sixthV_=parseFloat(sixthV);
   if (sixthT=="normal")  {totalseconds_+= sixthV_;} else {totalsilentseconds_+= sixthV_;}

    q="ficorange="+ficorange;
    q+="&loantype="+loantype;
    q+="&purchaseprice="+purchaseprice;
    q+="&downpaymentpc="+downpaymentpc;
    q+="&downpaymentamt="+downpaymentamt;
    q+="&seconds="+totalseconds_;
    q+="&silentseconds="+totalsilentseconds_;


    if (loantype=="" || purchaseprice=="" || (downpaymentpc =="" &&  downpaymentamt ==""))
      {
      //document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML= "";
      return;
      }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {
     // code for IE6, IE5
      xlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
//      alert (xmlhttp.responseText);
        var values=xmlhttp.responseText.split(",");
        //alert (xmlhttp.responseText);
          if (str!="loantype")
            {
                if (userChangedUpfrontMIP==false)
                {
                    document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["upfrontmippc"].value=values[0];
                    document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["upfrontmipamt"].value="";
                }
                if (userChangedMonthlyMIP==false)
                {
                    document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["monthlymippc"].value=values[2];
                    document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["monthlymipamt"].value="";
                }
                if (userChangedSSMonthlyMIP==false)
                {
                    document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["ssmonthlymippc"].value=values[6];
                    document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["ssmonthlymipamt"].value="";
                }
            }
            else
            {
              document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["upfrontmippc"].value=values[0];
              document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["upfrontmipamt"].value="";
              document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["monthlymippc"].value=values[2];
              document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["monthlymipamt"].value="";
              document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["ssmonthlymippc"].value=values[6];
              document.forms["frmCalculator"].elements["ssmonthlymipamt"].value="";
            }
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getMIPs.php?"+q,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Now I  have four input fields how can i assign this value in four input fields ?
 how can use same name using four input fields ?

Comment: Please post the complete code (all the 4 input fields).

Comment: @Cranio  updated my code please take a look

Comment: @A.Wolff i am not using Id that code i am using name only

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelectorAll and make a loop to assign each value, like this:

```
var selectElement = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="upfrontmippc"]');

for (var i = 0; i <= selectElement.length; i++){
    selectElement[i].value = "newValue";
}
```